# jquery : Change options of select tag list automatically

Tags: jquery, html

I have two drop down list items in select tag

first select tag has list of year 
second select tag has list of month

```
<SELECT id="year" onchange="showData();">
  <OPTION VALUE="2012">2012
  <OPTION VALUE="2011">2011
  <OPTION VALUE="2010">2010
  <OPTION VALUE="2009">2009
  <OPTION VALUE="2008">2008
</SELECT>

<SELECT id="month" onchange="showData();">
  <OPTION VALUE="jan">jan
  <OPTION VALUE="feb">feb
  <OPTION VALUE="mar">mar
        .
        .
  <OPTION VALUE="dec">dec
</SELECT>
```

so how i could change month after 5sec automatically & 60sec for year

what would be my jquery

```
function changeMonthYear() {    
    //what to code here to change option of select tag
    //automatically after some time 
    //say 5 sec per month & after 60 sec year will be changed
    showData();    
}

showData() {    
    //some logic will show data for selected year & month    
}
```

how to get fix it

Comment: What do you want to change it to? Otherwise either jQuery delay() or timeOut() will work. Won't it be confusing for the user with select boxes changing value all the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try it

```
function changeYear() {

        $('option:selected', '#year').removeAttr('selected').next('option').attr(
                'selected', 'selected'); //your id of select tag is 'year'

        showData();

    }

    function changeYearMonth() {

        $('option:selected', '#month').removeAttr('selected').next('option')
                .attr('selected', 'selected'); //your id of select tag is 'month'

        showData();

    }

    setInterval(changeYear, 60000);
    setInterval(changeYearMonth, 5000);

    showData(){

    //some logic will show data for selected year & month

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution, once it goes through all of the options, it'll continue again from the beginning:

```
var i=0;
function changeYear() {
  var count = $('#year option').length;
  i = (i == count) ? 0 : i;
  $('#year').val($('#year option').eq(i++).val());
}

setInterval(changeYear, 1000); // example is 1 second!
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deifwud/vYp2P/1/)

You'd have to do the same thing to change the month as well, just thought I'd leave this here as it's cleaner (in my opinion) than the other examples

Answer (score 0):

```
var i=0,j=0;

 function changeMonthYear() {

        //what to code here to change option of select tag
        //automatically after some time 
        //say 5 sec per month & after 60 sec year will be changed
        setInterval(showData('year'),1000*60);
        setInterval(showData('month'),1000*5);

    }
function showData(that)
{
if(that=='year')
{    
document.getElementById(that).getElementsByTagName('option')[i].selected=true;
    i++;
}
else
{
document.getElementById(that).getElementsByTagName('option')[j].selected=true;
j++;
}
}
changeMonthYear();
```